# Replace empty UITextfield with value

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I am building a digit only textfield.

I would like that when the text in textfield is "" replace it with "0".

I only manage to get the current text in read only.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Add the `editingChanged` delegate method to `textField` as follows:

In the `viewDidLoad()` method add the following code:

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textFieldChanged(_:)), for: .editingChanged);
```

And then, implement the method as follows:

```
@objc func textFieldChanged(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if let text = textField.text, text.isEmpty {
        textField.text = "0"
    }
}
```

The above method will be called every time the textField content changes.

You can also set the initial text of the `textField` to "0". Simply use `textField.text = "0"` in the `viewDidLoad()` method.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the text field to update when you have finished editing you can set up the action like this

[image: Editing Did End]

and then

```
    @IBAction func editingDidEnd(_ txtTest: UITextField) {
    if txtTest.text == ""
    {
        txtTest.text = "0"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
textField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleTextField(_:)), for: .editingChanged)

@objc private func handleTextField(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField.text == "" {
        textFiled.text = "0"
    }
}
```